# Open Source HTML/JS game(s) with license that would allow embedding in my app?

Tags: javascript, html5, open-source, licensing

I'm working on an educational app for kids. At the end of the sign-up process, the kids must wait for a confirmation from their parents in order to gain access to the app.

While they wait for this to happen, we want to let the kid play a simple game as a way to keep their interest up.

Is there a marketplace or repository for games with such a license that we could either purchase (affordably) or use for free in our own app?

Comment: Huh, usually it's "Where can I find free art/sounds/etc. for my game?". Where can I find free games for my game is a new one to me :)

Comment: If you ask this question on reddit with a quick explanation of your app, and make a convincing expression of passion for education, you'll probably find a lot of free offers. The indie game dev community is quite altruistic; reddit doubly so.

Comment: Just search through Github or Assembla. Is this app a desktop app or a mobile app?

Comment: This question is unfortunately still fundamentally going to generate a list of answers, each potentially equally valid.